# nginx find files after matching location pattern

Tags: file, nginx, location, match

Hello I am new to nginx and I thought that this would be easy , but it isn't as I imagined.
I am trying to map everything ater example.com/something/ to /home/user/examplefolder/
So i tried

```
   location /something/ {
        root   /home/user/examplefolder/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

But from the nginx error log i see that when i browse example.com/something/1.txt  it tries to find /home/user/examplefolder/something/1.txt and not /home/user/examplefolder/1.txt that i want.

I tried some variations with try_files and $1 with no luck. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

changing the root to alias did the trick. I start searching what is the difference between root and alias and then I realized that what I really wanted was alias and not root:
example:

```
   location /something/ {
        alias   /home/user/examplefolder/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Now example.com/something/1.txt is rooting to /home/user/examplefolder/1.txt